# Replace String with 0 in NiFi

Tags: regex, replace, etl, apache-nifi

I have a CSV file as follows:

**Time,Age, Address, Temperature 1,Temperature 2**

2018:09:20 18:07:56.941,12,NaN,NaN,0

2018:09:20 18:07:56.951,45,24,23,NAN

2018:09:20 18:07:56.981,34,NaN,57,0

The problem is some column have NANs and numbers mixed and I want to replace all the 'NAN' in a column to '0' value. I know we can use ReplaceText processor. 
Please find attached my config for ReplaceText but its not replacing any NAN TO 0.

Please help to achieve this. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Is it that none of either Nan or NAN are getting replaced by zero? If case is the problem try appending (?i) in the beginning of regex and make it (?i)\bNAN\b

Comment: Solved it. It was case sensitive problem. I was using NAN instead of NaN. Thanks

Comment: My guess was right. Glad it worked for you :)